# How can I search on list of values using Lucene Query interface

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search

Simplistic Problem description:

Lucene index has two fields per document: ID and NAME.

I want to make a query using the Lucene Query interface such that I can find all the documents where ID is 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR so on. The IDs to be searched will be in a list and can potentially have upto 30 elements.

If I was using the query parser I would have done something like

```
ID:(1 OR 2 OR 3)
```

But the application is already heavily committed to the Query interface and I want to follow the current pattern. Only way I can think of doing this with Query interface is create n term queries and group them using the Boolean query as below

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
(String searchId : lstIds)
{
    booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("ID", searchId)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
```

But is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combining queries togetheer with a `BooleanQuery` is the correct way to reproduce a query like `ID:(1 OR 2 OR 3)`.  The query parser will generate a BooleanQuery similar to what you provided for that syntax, so you are absolutely doing the right thing here.

You might be able to make use of  `PrefixQuery`, `NumericRangeQuery` or `TermRangeQuery` to simplify matters, if they actually suit your needs in practice, but there is nothing wrong with what you are doing already.

Answer (score 2):

`BooleanQuery` is the solution for handling *OR* operator as you have shown in the code but if you want simple alternative of the it you could also use simple `Query` and pass the **IDs** as **"1 OR 2 OR 3"**.

Here is the code snippet lucene 7.

```
Query query = new QueryParser("ID", analyzer).parse("1 OR 2 OR 3");
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 10);
```

OR if you have all the **OR** you could also use `QueryParser` default Operator.

Here is the code snippet for lucene 7.

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("ID", analyzer);
queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.OR);
Query query = queryParser.parse("1 2 3");
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 10);
```

I hope that work for you.